# can a user edit the value of the field through apex which are read only field on layout in salesforce?

Tags: read-only

I want some fields to be updatable from apex only and want those fields as read-only on layouts for all users. Can I do it by making fields as read-only on layout?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've used this technique myself.

The "read-only" flag on a page layout is only enforced when using the "save" button on the layout.

Alternatively, you could make a formula field that pulls data from the field you want to be "read only", and only include the formula field on the page layout.

Comment: *only enforced when using the "save" button*... and for actual API calls. Apex just ignores FLS by default.

Comment: @sfdcfox the 'read-only' flag on the page layout is separate from FLS.

Comment: Oops. Need more coffee, I suppose :p

Answer (score 1):

> I want some fields to be updatable from apex only and want those fields as read-only on layouts for all users. Can I do it by making fields as read-only on layout?

Mostly YES - the read only attribute on the page layout is distinct from the required attribute in the schema (established when the field is defined)

However, any user with [Edit Read Only Fields permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335725&type=1&mode=1) will be able to edit fields marked read only on the page layout (e.g. System Administrator profile users).